Estimator of accelerometer offset
I would like to estimate the offset of my accelerometer without using anything but measurements of the sensor. Is there any estimator for this? Averaging all the data points would probably do the trick, but poorly maybe?

You need to use measurements from the sensor and some sort of a ground truth -- like, you know that it's sitting on a bench, and the bench is level (or how off level the bench is).  Just the sensor doesn't help.

Remember that gravity exists, so except for free fall there will always be a 1g vector.

You could apply the method for calibrating magnetometers to your accelerometer.
If you rotate your accelerometer (ideally through all possible orientations), then the cloud of points will fall on an ellipsoid. From this, the necessary offset and gain corrections can be determined to make the ellipsoid a sphere with a 1g radius centred at the origin.
There are lots of papers published on this topic. To provide an unbiased and consistent fit of an ellipsoid to your data, I recommend using adjusted least squares.
